# Validación de formulario con jquery-validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estoy utilizando jquery-validation.js. Al momento de presionar el botón, me pide completar los campos, pero a la vez también manda el registro con los campos vacíos.

Si quito el jquery-validation, me valida con required de html y ese sí, no manda los datos.

¿Saben qué podría ser?

```
<form id="form_create" action="guardar.php" role="form" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" maxlength="30" minlength="3" required>
<button type="submit">REGISTRAR</button>
 </form>
```

y el script de JavaScript es:

```
<script src="plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#form_create').validate();
    });
</script>
```

perdon si no he sido claro, estoy utilizando ajax para guardar los campos de un formulario, que a su ves quiero validar con jquery-validate, el problema es que al presionar el boton de registro me especifica que tengo que llenar los campos, pero aun asi me envia el formulario con los campos vacios, como puedo evitar el submit, sin antes tener lleno todos los camppos del formulario

Comment: por favor, añade tu código

Comment: Hay que agregar las reglas de validación, así como lo tienes, no hace nada el plugin, revisa la documentación https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que darle submit a la forma hasta que pase la validación:

```
$("#form_create").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    }
});
```

`submitHandler` es un callback y el código definido dentro de el solo sera ejecutado cuando la validación sea exitosa.

Checa la documentacion [aqui](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).